# How to properly calculate averages in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

For things such as revenue per employee, or selling price per product

Which method would be correct, and are there cases where one will work and the other won't?

```
SUM(revenue)/SUM(employee)

/* OR */

AVG(revenue/employee)
```

I have been getting different answers with the above.

Comment: How much is the difference? It may be due to rounding, I assume.

Comment: Please share table structures, sample data and desired output.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur's suggestion is generally in line with what - let's say - "regular" users might expect.  That is, an average of the two separate totaled values.  That's not to say that the other way is incorrect (it's more an average of averages, though) - and in certain business cases you may be asked to calculate in that way.

Comment: The SUM of employee 1 and employee 9 is 10. I don't see how that's useful

Comment: `sum(employee)` seems either a strange number to calculate or a strange name for the column

Comment: Most people would compare `AVG(revenue)` with `SUM(revenue) / COUNT(employee)`. In which case the main difference would be that the first would effectively ignore rows with `NULL` revenue, the second would effectively treat such rows as having `0` revenue...  *(The average of `NULL,1,2,3` is `2`, but the `sum/count` would be `6/4` = `1.5`, unless the employee value is also NULL.)*

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your table structure it's difficult to know what's appropriate for you.

`SUM(revenue)/SUM(employee)` will just divide sum of all revenues by sum of employees (Or it can be count).

Where as  `AVG(revenue/employee)` will sum all the `revenue/employee` then divide the result by number of rows.

For your purpose I think first method will be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The two are doing two very different things.  One is calculating an *overall average* (the first one).  The second is calculating a weighted average treating each row separately.

As a simple example, consider a small table:

```
employees      revenue
 99               99
  1              100
```

The first returns `(100 + 99) / 100 = 1.99`.  This would be the same average if you had a table with 100 rows, one per "employee" and the  revenue were `revenue / employee` (i.e. `1` on 99 rows and `100` on 1 row).

The second returns `(99 / 99) + (100 / 1)` = 101.  This would be treating each row "equally".  That is, it is a biased average.  Sometimes this is useful, but not usually for counts.  For instance, it might be useful for rates of some sort.  Or it might be useful if the sizes on the rows are roughly the same.

In general, you would want the first format under most circumstances, based on the limited information in your question.